# Logoff Disconnected Session from Powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a script in power-shell which logoff the disconnected sessions from multiple servers and it sends me an email whenever it logoff the disconnected users from individual servers. As of now i am getting multiple emails when script log off users from multiple servers. I am trying to add functionality where it list the users which are getting logged off from script and send me only one email consisting of users list. Script is below:-

```
$servers = get-content “C:\Users\Desktop\server.txt” 
foreach($Server in $Servers) {
    try {
$disconnectedusers = @()
query user /server:$Server 2>&1 | select -skip 1 | ? {($_ -split "\s+")[-5] -eq 'Disc'} | % {logoff ($_ -split "\s+")[-6] /server:$Server /V ; $disconnectedusers += ($_ -split "\s+")[1]} 

If($disconnectedusers -ge 1)
{
    Send-MailMessage -to xx@xx.com -from sc@sc.com -Subject "List of Disconnected Users Logged Off" -Body "Disconnected User session for user:-$disconnectedusers on server $Server has been Logged off." -SmtpServer smtp.gmail.com
}
    }
    catch {}
    }
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Just to clarify.. you're looking for a single email that lists all the servers each user was logged off of? If so, I'd encourage you to look at using a hash table instead of an array. You could do $hashTable["user1"] += $server for example. Then enumerate over them when you build your email body.

Comment: Thats correct i am looking for single email consisting of user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a modified version that I thank you for that I will be schedule a task for this evening. I converted the email to HTML so there is a bit more in it than you might want but I think you will get the idea.

The main thing is creating your array out side of the foreach loop as well as the email sending if statement otherwise it will process per server in the loop.

```
$servers = get-content “C:\Users\Desktop\server.txt” 

$disconnectedusers = $null
$disconnectedusers = @()

$failed = @()
$style = "<style>
        body { 
        font-family: calibri;
        font-size: 12px;
        color: #000;
        }

        h1 {
        font-size: 16px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        }

        table {
        border: solid 1px #ddd;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        width: 80%;
        }

        th{
        background-color: #ddd;
        font-weight: bold;
        text-align: left;
        padding: 5px;
        }

        td {
        width: auto;
        padding: 3px 20px 3px 5px;
        text-align: left;
        border-bottom: #ddd solid 1px;
        }

    </style>"

foreach($Server in $Servers) {
try {

    query user /server:$Server 2>&1 | select -skip 1 | ? {($_ -split "\s+")[-5] -eq 'Disc'} | % {logoff ($_ -split "\s+")[-6] /server:$Server /V; $disconnectedusers += New-Object PSObject -Property @{"Server" = $Server; "SamAccountName" = $(($_ -split "\s+")[1])}} 
  }
  catch [Exception] {
             $failed += $($Server + ": " + $_.Exception.Message)
            }
  }

If($disconnectedusers) {

Send-MailMessage -to xx@xx.com -from noreply@xx.com -Subject "List of Disconnected Users Logged Off" `
-Body $($style + "<h1>Disconnected User sessions</h1><p>All sessions in the below table have been logged off.</p>"+ $($disconnectedusers | ConvertTo-Html -Fragment)) `
-SmtpServer "smtp.gmail.com" -BodyAsHtml -Priority "High"
}
```

Comment: Thanks i got the idea.